# TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400 while cursor user id search using tweepy cursor

Tags: python, dataframe, tweepy

[image]

**Python Script to Extract tweets of a particular username using Tweepy and Pandas**

Can any body help me out here with the error with cursor user id search using tweepy cursor

underlined error is the line     `list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]`

Keyword search works fine with this code changing `id` to `q`
I'm not sure what is the error here

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
import tweepy


# function to display data of each tweet
def printtweetdata(n, ith_tweet):
    print()
    print(f"Tweet {n}:")
    print(f"Username:{ith_tweet[0]}")
    #print(f"Description:{ith_tweet[1]}")
    

    print(f"Tweet Text:{ith_tweet[2]}")
    print(f"Hashtags Used:{ith_tweet[3]}")


# function to perform data extraction
def scrape(words, date_since, numtweet):
    
    # Creating DataFrame using pandas
    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'text', 'hashtags'])
    
    # We are using .Cursor() to search through twitter for the required tweets.
    # The number of tweets can be restricted using .items(number of tweets)
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, id=words, lang="en",
                        since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)
    
    # .Cursor() returns an iterable object. Each item in
    # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
    # get information about each tweet
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
    
    # Counter to maintain Tweet Count
    i = 1
    
    # we will iterate over each tweet in the list for extracting information about each tweet
    for tweet in list_tweets:
        username = tweet.user.screen_name
        # description = tweet.user.description
       
        hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']
        
        # Retweets can be distinguished by a retweeted_status attribute,
        # in case it is an invalid reference, except block will be executed
        try:
            text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
        except AttributeError:
            text = tweet.full_text
        hashtext = list()
        for j in range(0, len(hashtags)):
            hashtext.append(hashtags[j]['text'])
        
        # Here we are appending all the extracted information in the DataFrame
        ith_tweet = [username, text, hashtext]
        db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet
        
        # Function call to print tweet data on screen
        # printtweetdata(i, ith_tweet)
        # i = i+1
    filename = 'scraped_tweets.csv'
    
    # we will save our database as a CSV file.
    db.to_csv(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Enter your own credentials obtained
    # from your developer account
    consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    consumer_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    access_token_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    # Enter Hashtag and initial date
    print("Enter Twitter HashTag to search for")
    words = input()
    print("Enter Date since The Tweets are required in yyyy-mm--dd")
    date_since = input()
    
    # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
    numtweet = 100
    scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
    print('Scraping has completed!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=words, lang="en",
                        since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)
```

use `api.user_timeline` instead of api.search